# Compiling Objective-C on Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux

How can I program in Objective-C under Linux? Is there any compiler or IDE avaiable that allows me to program in that language?

Comment: Off topic since not related to your source code. But I gave an answer!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, but it's directly programming related.

Comment: This isn't off-topic, but it has been asked many times before, @BasileStarynkevitch.

Comment: Note that "Can I program on Linux using Objective-C?" and "Can I write iOS / OS X applications on Linux?" are two very different questions.

Answer (score 1):

There's this great website called [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/). They have some API's that help you with Objective C on Linux. The download & installation instruction page is [here](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/sources.html).

Yes, this question is a duplicate by the way. Check the links provided by Josh Caswell above to find even more detailed answers.

Answer (score -1):

Recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers (current version is 4.8 in october 2013) can be used as Objective C compilers (perhaps for some old dialect of Objective C).  On Debian or Ubuntu, install some `gobjc` package, e.g. `aptitude install gobjc-4.7`

However, this does not mean you can build with them programs for Apple hardware.

Comment: AFAICR GCC only support old dialect of the language. Please use clang.